# when killing chrome headless one zygotte process becomes a zombie process

Tags: google-chrome, headless, zombie-process

I am running a chrome headless instance in a docker container and when the given job is done i kill the chrome process. As i learned on the way of doing this; chrome starts 2 zygotte processes while it is started.

I send kill command and everytime i see one of the zygotte becomes a zombie process. I recently came to a solution as i get pids of all the child processes first;

> `pgrep -g <pid_of_main>`

then kill the one usually becomes zombie;

> `kill -9 <pid_of_usual_suspect> & wait & sleep 3`

then kill the main chrome process

> `kill -9 <pid_of_main>`

Succeeded so far, but i am curious that it would be the best practice.

What do you think about the way i am doing this?

All critics are welcome about my approach and the best practice to do this.